# $g_n \rightharpoonup g \implies T_{\phi}(g_n) \to T_{\phi} (g)$ ($T_\phi$ is bounded functional)

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Put $\dot{H}^1= \{f: \nabla f \in L^2\}.$

Choose $\phi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^d)$ (Schwartz space), and define $T_{\phi}:\dot{H}^1(\mathbb R^d) \to \mathbb C$ as $T_\phi (f)= \int_{\mathbb R^d} f(x) \phi (x) dx$, so that  $T_\phi$ is a bounded linear function on $ \dot{H}^1(\mathbb R^d),$  (that is, $|T_{\phi}(f)| \leq C \|\nabla f\|_{L^2},$ where $C$ is constant)

Assume that $g_n \rightharpoonup g$ in $\dot{H}^1$, that is $\int \nabla g_n \cdot \nabla h \to \int \nabla g \cdot  \nabla h$ for all $h\in \dot{H}^1.$

> Question: Can we expect that $T_{\phi}(g_n) \to T_{\phi} (g)$ in $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Yes of course $h = \phi$

Comment: @user1952009: Thanks. I have edited question.  Is it still true if replaced $L^2$ by $\dot{H}^1$?

Comment: $g_n(x) = n$...

Comment: @user1952009: Thanks, and sorry for the mess-up.  I should have define $\dot{H}^1$ by taking factoring out constants. See answer to this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166821/langle-nabla-g-n-nabla-h-rangle-to-langle-nabla-phi-nabla-h-rangle)

Comment: And then can we expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Riesz representation theorem to get $h \in \dot H^1$ with $$T_\phi(g) = \int \nabla g \cdot \nabla h$$
for all $g \in \dot H^1$.

Comment: Thanks. One side question: How I should make $\dot{H}^1$ Hilbert space? How should I take the factor by constants, etc. , so everything make sense? Can tell you me bit on this?

Comment: @abcd  No because as the OP defined it, it is not a Hilbert space. Take $g_n(x) = n$. Now if $\lim_{x \to \infty} g_n(x) = 0$ then yes

Comment: @user1952009: Thanks.  I understand constants creates a problem. But  can we expect to make it a Hilbert space by removing (factoring) constants?  Also OP mentioned that  it is a subspace of $\mathcal{S}'/ \mathbb C$ (I do not know how to justify this...)

Comment: @abcd I just did : $\lim_{x \to \infty}g_n(x) = 0$.

Comment: @abcd if $d = 1$, can you find $h$ ?

Comment: @user1952009: Thanks. I guess, we  may look at  $\dot{H}^1$ as a completion of $C_c^{\infty}$  (and so constants rule out)(see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2154077/inner-product-in-sobolev-space)) Please correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: @user1952009: It seems the dimension has not any role here?